# fragment hold null object when replacing

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

Im trying to generate new fragment and pull the data he hold but I get a nullObject exception

call to generate a new fragment:

```
    private void initializeBuyFragment(CardFragment cardFragment, View view) {
        Card card;
        if (random.nextInt(51) == 0)
            card = new WildCard();
        else card = new Card();

        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        cardFragment = CardFragment.newInstance(card);
        args.putSerializable("key",card);
        cardFragment.setArguments(args);
        makeFragment(cardFragment, view);
    }
    
    private void makeFragment(CardFragment cardFragment, View view) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .setReorderingAllowed(true)
                .replace(view.getId(), cardFragment)
                .commit();

    }
```

fragment implementation:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        card = (Card) getActivity().getIntent().getSerializableExtra(KEY);
        }

public static CardFragment newInstance(Card card) {
        CardFragment fragment = new CardFragment();
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putSerializable(KEY, card);
        fragment.setArguments(bundle);
        return fragment;
    }
```

I tried manually setting cardFragments card in initializeBuyFragment but when I debugged once it got to makeFragment it his card was once again null

how do I fix this?